# Get url with unique number at end [VB 2012]

Tags: regex, vb.net, url, unique

I haven't been using vb or anything close to it in the past year and I've forgotten how to use regex, I've searched around abit but nothing. So I'm wondering how I can  get this url that always end with unique numbers since it's a captcha url (I'm gonna put it in a picturebox and display it in my form) https://example.com/ex/captcha.php?gid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
It's always that exact lenght so it shouldn't be that hard and I'm using Visual Basic as stated before.

Comment: You don't need regex for this; just Split or Substring+IndexOf. Do a research of any of those and you will certainly find a solution quickly.

Comment: Yea, but if I use split I get 2 results since the unique number which I'm looking for comes up twice in the source. But thanks for the idea, will lookup Substring :)

Comment: No, Substring and split deliver the same result (and regex). You have to define the problem properly. For example, for the url you are including, you can use "captcha.php?gid=" as the splitting separator (it should work, isn't it?)

Comment: Currently trying that and it seems like it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the URL using the `Uri` and `HttpUtility` classes, like this:

```
Dim url As New Uri("https://example.com/ex/captcha.php?gid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
Dim parameters As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query)
Dim gid As String = parameters("gid")
```

Comment: I +1ed you; but this works just in ASP.NET isn't it?

Comment: @varocarbas No, it will work in any kind of project.  In order to use the `HttpUtility` class, you just need to reference the **System.Web.dll** library and import the `System.Web` namespace.  `Uri` is in the `System` namespace, and in the **System.dll** library, so it will be available by default.  The `NameValueCollection` is also in the **System.dll** library, but you will need to import the `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace.